# Elf header - Repetition of segments

Tags: linux, x86-64, elf

I am in doubt about some elf sections repetition.
I have the *X86_64 ABI* and *elf64 specification*.

First, all the tested programs found in /usr/bin and tested with `readelf` and `objdump` seem to give a practical answer, but still:

- is it possible for a program header to have more than 1 `PT_DYNAMIC` segment? (My answer: I see no reason for it but I may miss something.)
- in the pointed `PT_DYNAMIC` section, is it possible to have two `DT_RELA` arrays? (My answer: no, because otherwise we would not know for sure which array `DT_RELASZ` is defining. But, at the same time, some sources talk about "a" relocation table and not "the", so.. that would imply either multiple `PT_DYNAMIC`or multiple `DT_RELA`.. hmm hmm)

So, boys :), could you please confirm/contradict?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible for a program header to have more than 1 `PT_DYNAMIC` segment?

I don't believe anything in the ELF format spec prohibits this, but if you create a file with two `PT_DYNAMIC`s, it's likely that dynamic loader will get unhappy.

The usual way to write code in dynamic loader:

```
// ehdr points to Elf64_Ehdr in memory.
Elf64_Phdr *phdr = (Elf64_Phdr*)(ehdr + ehdr->e_phoff);
Elf64_Phdr *dyn = NULL;    
for (j = 0; j < ehdr->e_phnum; ++j) {
  if (phdr[j].p_type == PT_DYNAMIC) {
     dyn = phdr + j;
     // break;
  }
  // some other code
}
```

After completion of the above loop, `dyn` will point to the *last* instance of `PT_DYNAMIC`. But if "some other code" isn't present, and the "break" is commented in (i.e. we are looking *only* for `PT_DYNAMIC`), then `dyn` will point to the *first* instance of `PT_DYNAMIC`.

And if there is a mixture of both styles of loops in the loader (which is likely to be the case), then the loader will likely get confused and hit an assertion failure.

> is it possible to have two `DT_RELA` arrays?

The same two styles of loops answer applies here as well.

Comment: Yes so, nothing is enforced but the practice defines the rule, right?